# PHP-generated list of files : any way to have line breaks between different letters?

Tags: php, presentation

I'm using this code to generate an easily clickable list of the files present in a directory for which apache wouldn't allow to have a direct index :

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*.*") as $filename) {
    echo "<a href='".$filename."'>".$filename."</a>&nbsp; &#8212;&#8212; &nbsp; ".intval(filesize($filename) / (1024 * 1024))."MB<br />";
}
?>
```

Thing is, this is a folder with over 1000 files and it is extremely easy *not* to find quickly what we're searching for, haha.

I am asking just in case, please, would you see a way to insert line skips when we have a new first letter ?
After all the As, let's skip a line, before listing the Bs, and a new line skip between the Cs...

Thank you very much if you can help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work (assuming your filenames are ordered alphabetically already):

```
// create array of letters of the aplhabet
$letters = array("a","b","c","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z");    

foreach (glob("*.*") as $filename) {               
    if (in_array($filename[0],$letters)){ // check if first character of filename is in the array
        echo "<br />"; 

        if(($key = array_search($filename[0], $letters)) !== false) {
            unset($letters[$key]);  //remove letter from array
        }
    }

    echo "<a href='".$filename."'>".$filename."</a>&nbsp; &#8212;&#8212; &nbsp; ".intval(filesize($filename) / (1024 * 1024))."MB<br />";
}
```

So we are creating an array with all the letters of the alphabet. We are then checking if the first letter of the current string in our loop is in the array. If it is, we echo another break , and then remove that letter from the array, and then echo out our line as normal.

This will create an extra line break every time there is a new letter for the first time

If your filenames are not all lowercase, you may want to ensure you are comparing the correct case by using `strtolower()` for the reference to the filename string

Comment: I confirm, with strtolower, that did the job perfectly, you have my sincere gratitude ! For people coming through web searches, remember to add strtolower to the TWO occurences of $filename[0]

Comment: ARGH. Only noticed now : working for (95% of the files) filenames starting with a capital. But **ALL** files starting in lowercase were all pushed, in a single group, at the bottom of the list. All of them. Any idea why, maybe ?

Comment: I'm guessing it's because of the way the files are ordered during the loop. All the capitalized files are first (A-Z), then the lower case (a-z) second, something like: ABC...XYZabc...xyz. You could try loop through the files in another way, or push all the file names into an array, order it, and the loop through them

Comment: Allright, for reference, and if someone else needs the information, the solution was natcasesort(). In greater lengths : $files = glob("*.*"); natcasesort($files); foreach ($files as $filename) {

Answer (score 1):

This may help you.

```
            <?php
                $prev_file_f_char = '';
                foreach (glob("*.*") as $index => $filename) {
                    $base_name = strtolower(basename($filename));
                    if($base_name !== $prev_file_f_char && $index >0){
                        echo '<br/>';
                    }

                    echo "<a href='".$filename."'>".$filename."</a>&nbsp; &#8212;&#8212; &nbsp; ".intval(filesize($filename) / (1024 * 1024))."MB<br />";
                    $prev_file_f_char = $base_name[0];
                }
                ?>
```

Or if you want a group per character, then you can use this.

```
            <?php
                $all_files = array();
                foreach (glob("*.*") as $index => $filename) {
                    $base_name = strtolower(basename($filename));
                    $all_files[$base_name[0]][] = $filename;
                }
                ksort($all_files);
                foreach($all_files as $char=>$file_per_char){
                    echo '<h3>'.strtolower($char).'</h3>';
                    foreach($file_per_char as $index => $filename){
                        echo "<a href='".$filename."'>".$filename."</a>&nbsp; &#8212;&#8212; &nbsp; ".intval(filesize($filename) / (1024 * 1024))."MB<br />";
                    }
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, Abhisek ! For reference, the first code generated a new line break with every new filename, while the second code DID group letters with skipped line separations and a "letter title"... but the sorting was abnormal, for instance the "A" letter came between "C" and "D" O_o

Comment: Thanks. I will test it more. I used ksort to sort the alphabets in the key. And in the array keys the letter is the first alphabet of the main file name not the first letter of the file path.